# Remove security role permissions to deny login to CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have some users accessing CRM directly and some others trough a web portal. I want to disable the access to CRM of some users depending of their security role.

I can't disable users or remove the security roles they have because won't be able to read/write/own i.e Case entity.

1. Is there any permissions of the security role I can remove for deny this access? I research for it and can't find anything, I suppose the answer is No.
2. Any workaround for accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on UR12 or above, you can try use similar logic as Microsoft has implemented for [Control browsers which organization supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860463.aspx). Only difference is that instead of checking what browser user has, you would have to check his roles and decide if he can access CRM vie browser or not.

Look at 'How Does the Solution Work?' section for details.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it but is not the behavior I was expecting, before the redirection the user can see a preview of the Dashboard for the organization, and they shouldn't.

Comment: I think it would be really hard to get it exactly as you need. Even if user has completely empty role assigned, bits of UI are displayed to him. If it's data on the dashboard they you want to hide, you can just set something meaningless to be displayed as default (i.e. custom web page with "Access forbidden" label) for this user.

Answer (score 0):

Removing these permissions:

- Core Records: User Entity UI Settings
- Business Management: User Settings
- Customization: Customizations, System Form, View, Web Resource

Will deny move through CRM, but as @MarioZG says the user will see the UI with a warning message of 'Insufficient Permissions' to see the records.